# Prisma create single entity error: Missing argument but said argument is exist in the log

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

I'm building an app with NextJS, Prisma and MongoDB. I tried to make a post request but during the invocation, it fails, and an error message of missing arguments was logged. I have logged the data and I find it strange since the said missing argument is exist in the log. I will appreciate any kind of help! Thankyou!

This is the error message:

```
Error during the post creation PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.post.create()` invocation:
{
  data: {
    title: "this is a new post", // But here is the title
    desc: "this new post has many tags #cooking #testing #evening #life ##coding",
    img: "",
    slug: "this-is-a-new-post",
    userEmail: "testemail@test.com",
    postTags: {
      create: [
        { tag: { connect: { slug: "cooking" } } },
        { tag: { create: { slug: "pastry" } } },
        { tag: { create: { slug: "evening" } } },
        { tag: { connect: { slug: "life" } } },
        { tag: { connect: { slug: "coding" } } }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Argument `title` is missing. // It said title is missing.
    at Zn (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\freeCodeCamp\reactCourse\next-blog\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:117:5888)
    at ni.handleRequestError (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\freeCodeCamp\reactCourse\next-blog\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:124:6516)
    at ni.handleAndLogRequestError (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\freeCodeCamp\reactCourse\next-blog\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:124:6206)
    at ni.request (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\freeCodeCamp\reactCourse\next-blog\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:124:5926)
    at async l (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\freeCodeCamp\reactCourse\next-blog\node_modules\@prisma\client\runtime\library.js:129:10023)
    at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/posts/route.js:80:29)
    at async C:\Users\USER\Desktop\freeCodeCamp\reactCourse\next-blog\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:62609 {
  clientVersion: '5.6.0'
}
```

I am sure the title argument, as well as the other expected data from the schema is there and is received as it was present in the log, but somehow the error said "title" is missing.

I put several console.log to help to see if the data reach the create invocation.

Frontend code:

```
const postTread = async () => {
        console.log('Request Payload:', {
            title: title,
            desc: desc,
            img: imageURL,
            slug: slugify(title),
            postTags: tagify(desc)
        }); // This logs the payload
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/posts', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: title,
                desc: desc,
                img: imageURL,
                slug: slugify(title),
                postTags: tagify(desc)
            }),
        });
        
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw new Error('Failed to post');
        }

        // Refresh the page if request is successful
        const data = await res.json();
        if (data) {
            router.refresh();
        }
    };
```

Backend code:

```
export const POST = async (req) => {
    const session = await getAuthSession();
  
    if (!session) {
        return new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({ message: 'Not Authenticated!' }, { status: 401 })
        )
    };

    try {
        const body = await req.json();
        console.log('Body: ', body) // This logs the body
        const createdPost = await prisma.post.create({
            data: { 
                ...body, 
                userEmail: session.user.email,
                postTags: {
                    create: await Promise.all(body.postTags.map( async(tag) => {  // Similar to skip duplicates
                        const existingTag = await prisma.tag.findUnique({
                            where: { slug: tag }
                        })
                        if (existingTag) {
                            return { tag: { connect: { slug: tag }}}
                        } else {
                            return { tag: { create: { slug: tag }}}
                        }
                    })
                )
            }}
        });
        console.log("Created Post: ", createdPost) // But this did not log the created post
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(createdPost, { status: 200 }));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during the post creation', error);
        return new NextResponse(
            JSON.stringify({ message: 'Failed to POST' }, { status: 500 })
        );
    }
};
```

I think the issue is within the `prisma.post.create()` as both the `console.log('Request Payload:', {...});` and the `console.log('Body: ', body)` logs the data I expected but did not reach the `console.log("Created Post: ", createdPost)` but I still cannot find out where.

This is the prisma.schema i have for my database:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Tag {
  id    String @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  slug  String @unique
  title String
  img   String?
  posts PostTag[]
}

model PostTag {
  id       String @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  postSlug String
  tagSlug  String
  post     Post @relation(fields: [postSlug], references: [slug])
  tag      Tag @relation(fields: [tagSlug], references: [slug])

  @@unique([postSlug, tagSlug])
}

model Post {
  id        String @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  slug      String @unique
  title     String // This part is the title of the post
  desc      String
  img       String?
  views     Int @default(0)
  postTags  PostTag[]
  userEmail String
  user      User @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email])
  comments  Comment[]
}


// Rest of the schema (user, session, etc.)
```

Things i have done prior to posting this question:

1. I tried to change the code a bit explicit like this but also did not work.

```
export const POST = async (req) => {
     // Rest of the code
    try {
        const body = await req.json();
        console.log('Body: ', body) // This logs the body
        const createdPost = await prisma.post.create({
            data: { 
                title: body.title, 
                desc: body.desc, 
                img: body.img, 
                slug: body.slug, 
                userEmail: session.user.email,
                postTags: {
                    create: await Promise.all(body.postTags.map( async(tag) => {  // Similar to skip duplicates
                        const existingTag = await prisma.tag.findUnique({
                            where: { slug: tag }
                        })
                        if (existingTag) {
                            return { tag: { connect: { slug: tag }}}
                        } else {
                            return { tag: { create: { slug: tag }}}
                        }
                    })
                )
            }},
        });
        console.log("Created Post: ", createdPost) **// This did not log the created post**
    // Rest of the code
};
```

2. I have dropped all my records, so the collections is now currently empty (i have backed it up elsewhere) except user and session which my testemail exist.
3. I have run `npx prisma generate` `npx prisma db push` and `npx prisma validate` and everything passed just fine.
4. I tried to create a single post again with the same input but got thrown with same error.

**
Things I expect:**
The prisma create single entity invocation should work. Records will be created with all the arguments present within the request body.

this is my dev environment:

- OS: Windows
- Database: MongoDB
- Node.js version: node v18.17.1
- Prisma: Prisma v5.6.0

Answer (score 0):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding in your `postTags` creations. You shouldn't try to use nested promises and separate writes. The concept you are looking for is `connectOrCreate` which can update existing related records if they exist; or create new ones, if not. ([Related documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#connectorcreate).)

But before jumping into that, I would take a look at your schema. If I understand correctly, you want to have a situaton where a `Post` can have several `Tags` and naturally, a `Tag` can be attached to several `Posts`. This is called a many-to-many relationship. You can use an explicit relationship and a third, intermediate model to achieve this, but you can also use an implicit many-to-many relationship [as explained in Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations). (The documentation in question uses Posts and Categories which are exactly what you are looking for - wonderful!)

So, your implicit many-to-many schema's relevant parts would look something like this; it is only the `Post` model which holds the `slug` value as it is related to the post and other models don't need to repeat it.

```
model Tag {
  id    String @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  // The actual tag value. It should be unique so it can be used as an identifier
  name  String @unique
  // A Tag references 0 to many Posts
  posts Post[]
}

model Post {
  id        String @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  slug      String @unique
  title     String // This part is the title of the post
  // A Post references 0 to many Tags
  tags      Tag[]
}
```

As for the code, we want to create the post and use **nested writes** to connect to or create new tags:

```js
const body = await req.json();

const createdPost = await prisma.post.create({
  data: {
    title: body.title,
    desc: body.desc,
    img: body.img,
    slug: body.slug,
    userEmail: session.user.email,
    postTags: {
      connectOrCreate: body.tags.map((tag) => ({
        where: { name: tag.name },
        create: { name: tag.name },
      })
      )
    },
  },
});
```

This might not be a complete solution, but I hope this example as well as the documentation I linked to can help you solve it.